# Nginx having multiple sites-enabled breaks nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a weird issue happening in my Nginx server. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple services running on my servers internally.

This is kind of what I was trying to accomplish:

```
app1.mydomain.com ---                                         --- server 1: 10.0.0.2
                      \              10.0.0.1               / 
                       |--- nginx reverse proxy server --- |
                      /                                     \
app2.mydomain.com ---                                         --- server 2: 10.0.0.3
```

So I added the first one for app1, added the DNS settings in my domain provider, and everything worked perfectly. I was pretty excited so I went for the second one and then everything broke. I ran `nginx -t` and everything tested fine. The Nginx server was still running without error but I lost the ability to view app1.mydomain.com

The configs are basically the same except for the server_name and the proxy_pass

file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/app1.mydomain.com

```
server {
    server_name app1.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.2;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.mydomain.com

```
server {
    server_name app2.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.0.3;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

The way I did this was adding each config in it's own file in sites-available and then doing `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app1.mydomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

This worked perfectly for app1, but after doing that for app2 I lost access to app1 and app2 wouldn't appear.

In my router, I forwarded port 80 and 443 to the reverse proxy server 10.0.0.1 and those are the only rules on my router. On my domain name provider I have the correct A records pointed at the correct IP. I was able to verify everything works with app 1, but after doing a symlink for app 2 to go into sites-enabled and restart nginx I lose access to everything.

Any ideas as to what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: What does `nginx -T` show?

Comment: And what exact errors do you get?

Comment: The nginx configs shown here are incompete. Was this deliberate editing on the post or do you not have listen / certificate configuration?

Comment: `nginx -t` just shows `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
`

Comment: You need to use `nginx -T`, note the capital `T`. That will display the full configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@symcbean actually pointed out the answer. The configs I posted were incomplete. For app1 I used the exact config shown (which worked somehow) and then ran certbot which added the TLS config and listen variable to the config.

Then I added the config for app 2 (exactly as shown) and I didn't get any errors on the server but started getting the connection refused errors when I tried to access app 1 or app 2. After adding the listen config and restarting nginx everything started working.

Thanks!